# Disable Windows 10 Preview Builds

Tags: windows-10, windows-10-preview

On my laptop I installed a fresh copy of Windows 10 (had to swap the hard drive anyways, so I didn't upgrade from Windows 7). Then I activated the preview builds and got the th2-preview. In this version Windows 10 can be activated directly with a Windows 7 key, this is why I did that.

Up to there everything worked as expected, but now I am getting frequent Bluescreens that I don't get on my desktop PC that runs the regular non-preview Windows 10, so I want to disable preview builds on my Laptop as well and go back to the regular Windows 10. So I go to the Updates-Screen under Settings, and press "Stop receiving preview builds". Now it tells me that I can disable preview builds for a few days, but if I want to disable them permanently, I have to do something else. There is a link where they should tell me what to do. I click the link and then I get to a website, where they tell me, I need to go to the updates-screen and need to press "Stop receiving preview builds", which of course, leads me back to the very same website. So as you see there is a bit of recursivity going on.

Do you know any way to break that loop? ;) Is there any way to stop receiving preview builds?

Comment: Until the actual `Threshold 2` build is released what you want isn't possible.  Once that happens there are some tricks you can try.

Comment: Ok, makes sense that it doesn't want to downgrade from TH2-Preview to non-TH2. Do I need to do anything facy one Threshold 2 is out?

Comment: Until its released through Windows Update i can't really answer that question.

Comment: share the dmp files from **C:\Windows\Minidump** so that we can solve your actual issue: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem

Comment: The actual issue is that I don't want to be on preview software. The specific bluescreens will be the next thing to tackle, but there is no point in fixing Windows bugs if Windows keeps pushing new buggy software. I can take care of Bluescreens myself. They were only the trigger for me to really want to get off the insider program. I generally don't want to be on beta software. The only reason I went onto the insider program was so I can activate Windows. So the real actual problem is that I can't get off the Insider Program. I am aware of the xy-problem and this is not an instance of it.

Comment: Build 10586 is now stable and was released today to all users. so if you run this build, it is the latest stable version.

Comment: It finally made it onto my computer (for some reason it only appeared yesterday in Windows Update, might have something to do with regions) and now I was able to get off the Insider Program. Thanks for the help!

Comment: and are your BSOD issues solved?

Comment: Interestingly, so far I haven't had any more BSODs. I am not sure if that is just by chance or not, but as soon as I get any more BSODs I will investigate further. Thanks for asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Appearently you can only get off the Insider Program if your current build is the same as the most recent non-Insider build. Until then you have to wait for the non-Insider builds to catch up to your Insider build (for that better get onto the slow update track) and then you can leave the Insider Program.